# Hibernate issue: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session

Tags: java, hibernate, netbeans, exception

I found many times on stackoverflow this issue, but nothing from them gives me clear answer. For simplicity, there are only two tables **film** and **language** bound many to one relation. Everything done according [Netbeans Hibernate DVD Store tutorial](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/hibernate-webapp.html). Now, how to display in first page (**index.xhtml**) language. It looks like very straightforward. Simply add:

```
                  <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Language"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.languageByLanguageId.langName}"/>
                 </h:column>
```

(Comumn in table **language** **name** was renamed on **langName**)
But it issues still the same LazyInitializationException. I tried to obtain **languageId** and in this case I was successful. It means **#{item.languageByLanguageId.langName}** gives exception but **#{item.languageByLanguageId.languageId}** not. It is strange. So what happen, when I use explicit fetch according **languageId** if I can obtain its.

So I added in **FilmController.java** method for obtaining language:

```
  public String getLanguageById(Integer langId) {
    String language = helper.getLangById(langId);
    return language;
  }
```

And in **FilmHelper.java** (final version):

```
  public Film getFilmById(int filmId) {

Film film = null;

try {
    session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    org.hibernate.Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    Query q = session.createQuery("select count(film.filmId) from Film as film where film.filmId = :filmId");
    q.setParameter("filmId", filmId);
    Number count = (Number) q.uniqueResult();
    if (count.intValue() > 0)
      film = (Film) session.load(Film.class, filmId);
    tx.commit();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return film;
```

}

And yes, it works, I can obtain language name to modify index.xhtml:

```
<h:outputText value="{filmController.getLanguageById(item.languageByLanguageId.languageId)}"/>
```

Than I tried to modify FilmActor.hbm.xml to add lazy="false" and use origin simple solution in **index.xhtml** (**"#{item.languageByLanguageId.langName}"**):

```
<many-to-one name="languageByOriginalLanguageId" class="dvdrental.Language" lazy="false" fetch="select">
        <column name="original_language_id" />
    </many-to-one>
```

Again it works properly. Even if I set **lazy="proxy"** or **lazy="no proxy"**. But still I don't understand, how to use this default attribute **lazy="true"**. If I try to keep whole document in one session (don't do commit, which causes end of session), there is another Exception issue. It looks like, that **lazy="true"** doesn't meet in any time proper result.

Answer (score 1):

With setting `lazy=true` attribute you are allowing hibernate to delay association retrieving. So when you disable `lazy=false` then hibernate will immediate do its fetching method, just after parent instance is retrieved. Yours problem will be solved if you set `fetch="join"`.

> Join fetching: Hibernate retrieves the associated instance or
>   collection in the same SELECT, using an OUTER JOIN.

Your example;

```
<many-to-one name="languageByOriginalLanguageId" class="dvdrental.Language" fetch="join">
        <column name="original_language_id" />
</many-to-one>
```

You can look at fetch and lazy as how and when, respectively. In your example `lazy=false` solved your problem but still two queries where done because your `fetch` method was `select`. 
[Hibernate Fetching Strategies](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching)

**UPDATE**

Once when object is lazy initialized, you have only properties of your entity and lazy initialized association (only id you have). Then that object is passed for further(transaction is committed already) use and you want to use one of lazy initialized association(in your case Language) and got exception. This is happening because you are accessing lazy object and your transaction is already commited, so hibernate wants to execute your second query without success (fetch="select"). This can be fixed by moving the code that reads association to just before the transaction is committed.

When your object is detached and your current session is closed then you must do

```
Hibernate.initialize(entity)
```

to assign your detached entity to another session.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for explanation. I tested your advice. It works and I suppose, that join should be quicker than two distinct selects (it depends on indexes, optimizer, etc.), but still when I try combination **lazy="true"** and **fetch="join"** it again fails:

```
<many-to-one name="languageByOriginalLanguageId" class="dvdrental.Language" lazy="true" fetch="join">
  <column name="original_language_id" />
</many-to-one>
```

Even if exception is different, still no succes:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at controller.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:30)
```

However, there are clearly explained three ways, how to avoid problems with default or explicit **lazy="true"**.